# Turkish transit visa for Filipino citizen?

Tags: transit, transit-visas, turkey, filipino-citizens, pegasus-airlines

I am a Filipino traveling to Georgia from Saudi Arabia. I have a layover in Turkey (Sabiha airport) for 16 hours and boarding the same airline Pegasus.

Do I need a transit visa? I am just worried, though I have read some questions like this but from a different country, and they don't need a transit visa if they won't leave the transit lounge. I hope it will apply also to me.

Comment: Is it a single ticket, or you booked two of them separately?

Comment: The flights I find in google flights filtered by pegasus on this route shows only 6 hour layovers. Probably a mistake in the question.

Comment: @AnishSheela I can see multiple connections that have 15-16 hour connections in SAW from TIB to all of DUH,DMM and JUD (eg, PC315 connecting to PC690). There are options with shorter connections, but they may have been sold out/priced higher.

Comment: Pegasus is a LCC, pretty sure it is two separate tickets even if booked in one go

Comment: @NicolasFormichella Pegasus definitely sell single tickets with multiple legs.  This may or may not be a single ticket, but it it definitely possible.

Answer (score 8):

Filipino citizens do not require a visa to transit Istanbul Sabiha Gökçen (SAW) as long as you have less than 24 hours between flights, and as you say, as long as you do not leave the transit area of the airport.

This of course presumes that you are able to stay in the transit area.  If you are checking bags, and both of your flights are on the same ticket (ie, purchased together) then they will be checked through to your final destination.  However if you booked the tickets separately there is a possibility that the airline will require you to collect and re-check them at SAW - which will require you to leave the transit area, which will require a visa.

However even if you don't need to leave the transit area, 16 hours is a long time to spend in an airport!

As a Filipino citizen you are eligible to apply for an e-Visa to enter Turkey. You [apply for the e-Visa online](https://www.evisa.gov.tr/en/), and it will likely be approved immediately - for a cost of US$20.  This will allow you to enter the country during your stopover.